# cy.pa11y typescript error: Property 'pa11y' does not exist on type 'cy & CyEventEmitter'.ts(2339)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cypress, e2e-testing, tsconfig

I am using Cypress 10.4.0 and I am using Typescript.
The test is running fine, but my editor VSCode in this case has a `ts error` as the image below:

[image: ts(2339) error]

Any ideas how to fix it? Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "../node_modules",
    "target": "es5",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "types": ["cypress", "@testing-library/cypress"],
    "paths": {
      "@cypress/*": ["../cypress/support/*"],
      "@interceptors/*": ["../cypress/interceptors/*"],
      "@fixtures/*": ["../cypress/fixtures/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include `cypress-audit` in the `tsconfig-json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "../node_modules",
    "target": "es5",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "types": ["cypress", "@testing-library/cypress"],
    "paths": {
      "@cypress/*": ["../cypress/support/*"],
      "@interceptors/*": ["../cypress/interceptors/*"],
      "@fixtures/*": ["../cypress/fixtures/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["./**/*.ts", "../node_modules/cypress-audit"] // This was missing.
}
```